# grub rescue mode on kali linux (usb flash)

Tags: linux, grub, grub2, kali-linux, rescue

Trying to create Kali Linux live USB persistance.
Split the usb like this:

|| first part FAT for data || second part FAT for LINUX || third part for persistance||

Then set "bootable" flag in gparted on /dev/sdb2

Format: `mkfs.vfat -n linux /dev/sdb2`

Then trying to copy kali linux files, like [this](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install):

```
`dd if=kali-linux-1.0.9a-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb2 bs=512k`
```

Now, I reboot my laptop, select Flash Drive as boot-able device,
and have this:

```
    grub error: File not found...
    grub entering rescue mode
    grub rescue>
```

Then, I tried out things mentioned in the following links:

[bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169650](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169650)

[adw0rd.com/2010/4/5/grub-rescue/](http://adw0rd.com/2010/4/5/grub-rescue/)

[askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem)

and nothing helps!

```
    grub rescue> ls
    hd0, (hd0,msdos3), (hd0,msdos1), (hd0,msdos2), (hd1,msdos4), (hd1,msdos3), (hd1,msdos1), (hd1,msdos2), hd1
    grub rescue> set
    prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
    root=(hd0,msdos2)
```

I have already spent 3 days to solve this problem and can't find a solution.

P.S.
fdisk shows for /dev/sdb2

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb2: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
193 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1358 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0a9a1b1a

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb2p1   *          64     6324223     3162080   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2p2         6324224     6485375       80576    1  FAT12
```

Are it's normal partition table for Kali Linux?

Comment: I partly solve the problem by reformatting partition /dev/sdb2 and reinstall grub on it.

Now. I have new problem. Can't start kali linux from grub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve your problem by following these steps :

Find out which devices are available by typing `ls`

Set to the correct value :

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
normal
```

The above commands will get you out of the rescue mode to the normal terminal mode. 
After the above commands you can go ahead and start the rest of the settings.

```
insmod linux 
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro
```

If the above command doesnt work try this :

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-14-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro
boot
```

Additionally dont forget to update your grub

Update the GRUB config file.:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reinstallation of Grub on the device:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't help.
I found, that:
ls (hd0, msdos1) is my first partition with media data
ls (hd0, msdos2) didn't show anything.
All other "partitions" shows "unknown filesystem"

After set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/grub and root=(hd0,msdos2) command insmod normal shows "file not found". Any other combinations of prefix, root, and path to grub didn't help.

Comment: For me this does help in fixing grub and getting it to boot, but then when I reboot I get the same error :(

Comment: I got into rescue mode after updating Kali from the GUI. This is terrible! Linux feels so fragile! When doing the `insmod normal`, I get a `file '/grub/i368-pc/normal.mod' not found`. If anyone has any ideas flying, let me know, because I have no idea what I am doing...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem too after deleting my kali-linux partion from Windows disk management. I was able to solve the problems though and I think you can use this as well:

1. You must have a minimum of 4G flash drive.
2. Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download and download boot repair iso file (780MB in size).
3. Download Rufus ISO burner https://rufus.ie/ and install (1.1MB in size or above). If you don't know how to use Rufus, search it on the Internet, then burn the boot repair ISO on your flash drive,
4. Make sure your OC is turned off, plug in your flash drive, power up your PC and press F9 for boot option. Make sure you boot from USB.
5. After booting from USB the repair will take over from there with little question from you. It's as easy as that.